# JTable is empty after adding Components

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have problem with JTable, I am trying to put in each row JComboBoxes and JTextFields but when I load app, my table is empty. Functions getCmb* and getTxt* return JComboBox and JTextField and that works fine, I checked.

```
        JTable tblCommands;
        String[] columnTitles=new String[]{"Command","Offset","Type","Value","Units","Value Type","R/W"};
        Object[][] data=new Object[20][7];
        int row=0;
        for(MessageCSVView message:messageContainer.getRows()){
            data[row][0]=message.getCmbName();//this works 
            data[row][1]=message.getCmbOffset();//this works 
            data[row][2]=message.getTxtType();//this works 
            data[row][3]=message.getTxtValue();//this works 
            data[row][4]=message.getTxtUnit();//this works 

            data[row][5]=message.getTxtValueType();//this works 
            data[row][6]=message.getCmbRW();//this works 
            row++;
        }
        tblCommands=new JTable(data,columnTitles);
```

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong ?

Comment: please read this tutorial http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox and with example about JComboBox

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the way input works with `JTable`.

You'll need to create `TableCellEditor` implementations and add them to each column of your table.

Take a look at Swing tutorial on `JTable` for further information.

Comment: Correct answer +1. And thanks for pointing the mistake out in my post.

Answer (score 1):

**Example Snippet**

```
public class JComboBoxCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {    
    JComboBox comboBox;    
    public JComboBoxCellEditor() {
        super(new JComboBox());  
        comboBox = (JComboBox) getComponent();
    }
}
```

Then include it like below,

```
TableColumn column = myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
column.setCellEditor(new JComboBoxCellEditor());
```

**Further reading:**

Here is your best bet, [Swing tutorial for JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Comment: This snippet won't compile because `JComboBox` is NOT a `TableCellEditor`.